# How to communicate 'externally' between Adobe Animate CC animations?

Tags: javascript, canvas, adobe-animate

From the script in the html page, I'm trying to control what happens in the Adobe Animate CC animations I've created.  For example, here you'll see a script that doesn't work that's trying to tell the ship animation to gotoAndPlay(5).   Anyhow, the ship animation is not responding to that.  I'm guessing it's because I'm not addressing/naming it correctly.  Help me talk to my animations.  See the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Lets talk to each other</title>


<script src="http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/tweenjs-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/movieclip-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="ship.js"></script>
<script src="car.js"></script>

<script>
function init () {

    var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_ship");
    exportRoot = new libs_ship.ship();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(libs_ship.properties.fps);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);


    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_car");
    exportRoot = new libs_car.car();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(libs_car.properties.fps);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}

function Tell_Canvas_Ship_to_gotoAndPlay5(){
    canvas_ship.gotoAndPlay(5);
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="init();" style="background-color:#D4D4D4">
    <canvas id="canvas_ship" width="300" height="250" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas_car" width="300" height="250" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I figured it out and answered it here:
[Post with same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868648/how-to-communicate-between-two-animated-canvas-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've received help and will now share the answer. You are welcome. Just invite me over for breakfast sometime.

In Adobe Animate, you'll need to change the library namespace (in the Publish settings in the Advanced tab I think) to lib_jerry or whatever custom name you come up with... so long as it's different than the other animation. Then just follow the setup in this code. You can call the functions from within the Animate animations.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Container</title>

<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
<script src="tommy.js"></script>
<script src="jerry.js"></script>
<script>

var canvas, stage, tomtom, jerjer;
function init() {

    var exportRoot;

    //Tommy
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_tommy");

    tomtom = new lib_tommy.tommy();
    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(tomtom);
    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib_tommy.properties.fps);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);


    //Jerry
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_jerry");

    jerjer = new lib_jerry.jerry();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(jerjer);
    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib_jerry.properties.fps);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);

}

function button_from_tommy_was_clicked(){   
    tomtom.gotoAndPlay(5);
}

function button_from_jerry_was_clicked(){   
    jerjer.gotoAndPlay(5);
}

</script>

</head>
<body onload="init();" style="background-color:#D4D4D4;margin:0px;">
    <canvas id="canvas_tommy" width="970" height="90" style="background-color:#727272"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas_jerry" width="970" height="90" style="background-color:#727272"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "canvas_ship" is the ID of your actual canvas element. I *think* what you are trying to do is control the content you are adding to it.

If so, you can call `gotoAndPlay` on the `exportRoot`, which is a MovieClip instance with that API.

```
exportRoot.gotoAndPlay(5);
```

The issue you will have though, is that once you create your canvas_ship stage and content, you are overwriting the variables. I recommend changing the name of the second canvas, exportRoot, and stage.

You could also add both elements to one canvas. Is there any reason you are using two canvases, other than that you used the exported content from 2 FLAs?

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas_ship");
var ship = new libs_ship.ship();
var car = new libs_car.car();
stage.addChild(ship, car);
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
```

Where is your `Tell_Canvas_Ship_to_gotoAndPlay5` method getting called from? Is it a frame script in Animate/Flash?

Comment: This actually answered my question too.  Thanks Lanny!