# How to Communicate between Two Animated Canvas Elements?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, adobe-animate

I want to communicate between two animated canvas elements.

I’ve made two html5 canvas js animations with Adobe Animate CC.    I’ve put both of these elements into one html page.  I can successfully call functions from within those animations – the alerts are triggered successfully in the code below.

I want to call functions from one animation to control the other animation.   I need help knowing how to correctly call/name/address the animations.   So far I get no response with the `canvas_ship.gotoAndPlay(12);` and `canvas_car.gotoAndPlay(7);`, and I've spent hours trying different references.   I’m not a big coder, but I’m sure this is a simple matter.  Any help is appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Multiple Canvas Animations Talking to Each Other</title>


<script src="http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/tweenjs-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/movieclip-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="ship.js"></script>
<script src="car.js"></script>

<script>
function init () {

    var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_ship");
    exportRoot = new libs_ship.ship();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(libs_ship.properties.fps);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);


    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_car");
    exportRoot = new libs_car.car();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(libs_car.properties.fps);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}

function tell_Ship_what_frame_to_go_to(){
    alert("tell_Ship_what_frame_to_go_to was triggered");
    canvas_ship.gotoAndPlay(12);  //This line does not work.
}
function tell_Car_what_frame_to_go_to(){
    alert("tell_Car_what_frame_to_go_to was triggered");
    canvas_car.gotoAndPlay(7);  //This line does not work.
}


</script>
</head>

<body onload="init();" style="background-color:#D4D4D4">
    <canvas id="canvas_ship" width="300" height="250" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas_car" width="300" height="250" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856273/how-to-communicate-externally-between-adobe-animate-cc-animations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've received help and will now share the answer.  You are welcome.  Just invite me over for dinner sometime.

In Adobe Animate, you'll need to change the library namespace (in the Publish settings in the Advanced tab I think) to lib_jerry or whatever custom name you come up with... so long as it's different than the other animation.   Then just follow the setup in this code.   You can call the functions from within the Animate animations.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Container</title>

<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
<script src="tommy.js"></script>
<script src="jerry.js"></script>
<script>

var canvas, stage, tomtom, jerjer;
function init() {

    var exportRoot;

    //Tommy
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_tommy");

    tomtom = new lib_tommy.tommy();
    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(tomtom);
    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib_tommy.properties.fps);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);


    //Jerry
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_jerry");

    jerjer = new lib_jerry.jerry();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(jerjer);
    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib_jerry.properties.fps);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);

}

function button_from_tommy_was_clicked(){   
    tomtom.gotoAndPlay(5);
}

function button_from_jerry_was_clicked(){   
    jerjer.gotoAndPlay(5);
}

</script>

</head>
<body onload="init();" style="background-color:#D4D4D4;margin:0px;">
    <canvas id="canvas_tommy" width="970" height="90" style="background-color:#727272"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas_jerry" width="970" height="90" style="background-color:#727272"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```